# Turn-by-turn navigation screen orientation

Tags: google-maps-navigation

I had a question about screen orientation in the Google turn-by-turn navigation app. Previously the screen would orient as you would expect with the maps/arrows pointed in the direction of travel(with a 3D-esque view of what's coming).

However of-late(I suspect after an update or so), the maps are always oriented to point north and the app just plots your current location giving you a top-view of the map(as you would see in the normal Google Maps app). Is there any way to change this back to how it previously was?

I am using a Droid Incredible running Android 2.3.4(Gingerbread). Also, just to clarify the above post is about the turn-by-turn navigation app(which can be fired up from Google Maps or as a standalone - 'Car Panel' or 'Navigation') and not Google Maps, per se.

Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the app cache (and data) seems to have resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Tap the red and white diamond icon in the upper left-hand corner of the map screen to change orientation/view setting in Navigation.  That should get you back to the "behind the wheel" turn-by-turn view you want.  (Just a note that the red half of the icon will always point north no matter what mode you're in.)  I was stuck on this one too and there's no option in the "Settings" menu to define the orientation view.